# Ionic Cordova Push alerts issue with vibration and sound iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I'm playing around with ionic and the phone gap-plugin-push notification plugin, but can't seem to get the sound to play. I'm initialising the push with:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
                        "debug": true,
                        "onNotification": function(notification) {
                            var payload = notification.payload;
                        },
                        "onRegister": function(data) {
                            console.log(data.token);
                        },
                        "pluginConfig": {
                            "ios": {
                                "badge": true,
                                "sound": true, 
                                "alert":true,
                                "vibration": true
                            }
                        } 
                    });
```

I can send a push alert via the ionic push REST api https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push like the below which sends an alert successfully but without sound or vibrations.

```
{
  "user_ids":[
    "14"
  ],
  "notification":{
    "alert":"Hello World!"
    }
  }
```

I seem to have tried a bunch of different combinations of the above, including using iOS specific params as per the docs:

```
{
  "user_ids":[
    "14"
  ],
  "notification":{
    "alert":"Hello World!",
    "ios":{
      "expiry": 1454927886239,
      "badge":1,
      "priority": 10,
      "contentAvailable": 1,
      "payload":{
          "sound":"default"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing triggers any vibration or sounds. I'm a bit confused as to the crossover in the docs from the phone gap-plugin-push to the the ionic push docs and what to pass in the body of the request to get the sounds and vibration working. Anybody have a working example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://asfandi.com/index.php?page=open_source_contribution for cordova vibration, If this link does not work for you then visit http://asfandi.com and click on "Open Source Contribution".